# How can I use a custom service worker events in vue-cli with typescript

Tags: typescript, service-worker, vue-cli

I have a Vue-cli project with and want to enable offline support (pwa, progressive web app functionality). Therefore I installed the PWA-Plugin for the vue cli.

In the vue.config.js I configured the Pwa and the workbox like following:

```js
...
pwa: {
    name: 'projectname',
    // configure the workbox plugin
    // workboxPluginMode: 'GenerateSW',
    workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
    workboxOptions: {
      // swSrc is required in InjectManifest mode.
      swSrc: 'src/service-worker.js',
      }
}
...
```

Now I want to inject my following additional events into the service-worker (from src/service-worker.js)

```js
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
    console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: "${event.data.text()}"`);
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    console.log(event.request.url);
    // event.respondWith(() => {
    //     fetch(event.request)
    // }
    // );
});
```

In the registerServiceWorker.ts I commented the environment-check so the service-worker is also served on my localhost.

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import { register } from 'register-service-worker'
// if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready () {
      console.log(
        'App is being served from cache by a service worker.\n'
      )
    },
    cached () {
      console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
    },
    updated () {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
    },
    offline () {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
    },
    error (error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
    }
  })
// }
```

But when I check the service-worker.js which is served to the browser I only see the default service-worker

```js
/* eslint-disable-next-line no-redeclare */
/* global self */

// This service worker file is effectively a 'no-op' that will reset any
// previous service worker registered for the same host:port combination.

// It is read and returned by a dev server middleware that is only loaded
// during development.

// In the production build, this file is replaced with an actual service worker
// file that will precache your site's local assets.

self.addEventListener('install', () => self.skipWaiting())

self.addEventListener('activate', () => {
  self.clients.matchAll({ type: 'window' }).then(windowClients => {
    for (const windowClient of windowClients) {
      // Force open pages to refresh, so that they have a chance to load the
      // fresh navigation response from the local dev server.
      windowClient.navigate(windowClient.url)
    }
  })
})
```

I would expect it would look like:

```js
self.addEventListener('install', () => self.skipWaiting())
self.addEventListener('activate', () => {
  self.clients.matchAll({ type: 'window' }).then(windowClients => {
    for (const windowClient of windowClients) {
      // Force open pages to refresh, so that they have a chance to load the
      // fresh navigation response from the local dev server.
      windowClient.navigate(windowClient.url)
    }
  })
})
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
    console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: "${event.data.text()}"`);
});
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    console.log(event.request.url);
});
```

Further things I tried:

- using src/service-worker.**ts** instead of a js file does not help.
- using "vue-cli-service serve --mode production" also returns the false service worker.
- when I put my additional code in the public folder and manually register the service worker I got the "push"-test to work, but the offline-caching obviously did not work.

Answer (score 2):

First thing I had to do was add "devserver" to ***vue.config.js***:

```js
  devServer: {    
    https: true,
  },
  pwa: {
    // configure the workbox plugin
    workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
    workboxOptions: {
      swSrc: 'src/service-worker.js',
      swDest: 'service-worker.js',
    }
  }
...
```

Further I did not manage to run the vue-cli service without Certificate-Error and serving the production environment (even though I build via production mode, with the correct service worker in the ***/dist*** folder).

My current workaround is using a .NetCore application where I copy the code to ***wwwroot*** and then run the solution with IISExpress. I use the `npm run ship`.

```js
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "copydist": "xcopy .\\dist ..\\wwwroot\\ /s /y",
    "ship": "npm run build && npm run copydist",
    "test": "set NODE_ENV=production && npm run build && serve -s dist"
  },
```

Things I still haven't figured out are:

- How I can use typescript for the serviceworker.
- How to avoid the .NetCore workaround with a valid localhost cert.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution for serving the application using https locally you can use the npm serve package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve).

Generate your certificate using mkcert (https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert).

```
serve -s -l 8080 --ssl-cert localhost.pem --ssl-key localhost-key.pem dist
```